# why my image texture doesn't appear?

Tags: texturing, uv

In edit mode, I can see my texture applied to my object. But when I exit edit mode, or when I try to render, the texture does not appear. Why is this happening? [image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the material asssigned to the faces?

Comment: yes it's assigned